# CryptographicException (The parameter is incorrect) on Windows 8.1 but not Windows 7

Tags: c#, cryptography, windows-8.1, rsa

I have some code that's been working fine on Windows 7 but fails now that I've started using a Windows 8.1 dev box (see repro code below).

Is RSA different on Windows 8.1 vs. Windows 7?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


namespace RsaBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("rvco6d27bsw2fw5qx7okdcu5jahd1ifh22is76k5xyau3wjv7plo0rom66h2434tvm29cmq2ov6mbjo30bymb14j2dst5fzy7pd");
            var exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1ekh");

            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //Get an instance of RSAParameters from ExportParameters function.
                var rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

                //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
                rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
                rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;

                //Import key parameters into RSA.
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo); // on Windows 8.1, this throws
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147024809
  _message=The parameter is incorrect.

  HResult=-2147024809
  IsTransient=false
  Message=The parameter is incorrect.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP, Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
       at RsaBug.Program.Main() in d:\sandbox\2015\RsaBug\RsaBug\Program.cs:line 24
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: @GregS: your base-36 suggestion was spot on. To add to the difficulty, it turns out that the resulting array needs to be reversed before it is used for the RSA parameters. Would you like to propose an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the alphabet present it is likely that the modulus and exponent are base-36 encoded.